# How to use Bridge edge loop to create arch

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I tried to use bridge edge loops to connect two faces into the arch, but it behave quite weirdly. Could you suggest how can I fix it?

Thanks,
Robert[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just increase the *Number of Cuts* parameter in the operator settings panel (<kbd>F6</kbd>), and adjust the *Smoothness* value to a desired outcome.

[image]

Comment: Can the same system also work in terms of '' lines '' and not edges?

Comment: Not sure I dunderstand what you mean by "lines"

Comment: From a point, a vertex, in 2D  e not in edges

Comment: No I don't think that's possible, there are no faces to take normals from, so no arch direction can be determined

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you use the <kbd>W</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*, you need to tilt your faces a bit. If you use the <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > *Bridge* (*LoopTools* addon), you don't need though.

[image]