# How to create an arch with bridge edge loops consistently

Tags: modifiers, edges, loop

I am trying to create an arch.  I followed the instructions from 2:49 time at [How to use Array to build an arch - Blender 2.8 Tutorial](https://youtu.be/FkgXOexHncM?t=168) and got it to work, but then after that, it failed to work again producing an [S shape](https://gyazo.com/8d233d9966404760f09f913517c10dd9) rather than a curve.

It is quite frustrating.  I've been doing it over and over and am unable to figure out how I am mucking it up. The answer provided on this site for [how-to-use-bridge-edge-loop-to-create-arch](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126808/how-to-use-bridge-edge-loop-to-create-arch) did not seem to apply to my issue.

The most aggravating thing is that I can make it work once in a while but not consistently, so it's got to be something simple.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** This is now a confirmed bug: [Bridge Edge Loops operation has inconsistent results](https://developer.blender.org/T75181)

---

You need to duplicate the objects in *Object Mode* and join them.
Duplicating them in Edit Mode gives weird results.

*Duplicated in Object mode and joined. Works as expected.*

[image]

*Duplicated in Edit Mode. Gives weird results.*

[image]

Comment: Hi. Do you know the "why"? I mean if you compare indices (vert, edges) they are the same in both cases (if i'm correct).

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. Indices were also my first guess. Now I'm out of ideas... :)

Comment: I reported it as a bug, perhaps the mighty developers will find out what's causing it :).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: Might be that the second face's normal is facing the opposite way for some reason

Comment: @Gorgious Yeah, that solves the inverted faces. But the shape is still a weird 'S' curve. Some weird stuff going on here... :)

Comment: I still cannot get this to behave in a consistent manner.  I have gone and made two arches perfectly and then the third one fails and I do it over and over making certain I am in object mode for the duplication and it still behaves oddly.  I am literally banging my head right now.

Comment: @JLLacy Hello :). I reported it as a bug. Until it's fixed, perhaps the *Spin tool* could be an alternative.