# how to extrude along a path to connect 2 meshes

Tags: modeling

[image: the areas I need connected and the path I want to connect them along]

I need to connect a couple of areas along a path. They where 2 separate models I am combining and I am having some trouble. The modles are an engine and turbo. I need to connect the selected areas along the selected path, and have it look like a pipe. Anyone know how to do that. It is all now one object.

Comment: [Bridge Edge Loops](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126808/how-to-use-bridge-edge-loop-to-create-arch/126844#126844) will likely not give you enough control, so probably make the path a separate object convert it to a bezier curve, adjust as necessary then merge at the end

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it this way but you have something close to it with 2 *LoopTools* > *Loft* or *Bridge*. Also, you'll have a better topology if the first and last selection have the same amount of vertices. Activate the *LoopTools* addon, then:

**LoopTools > Loft**

Select one of your circles, duplicate it several times where you want the pipe to follow. Select the first and last circle and all the duplications. Then right click to make the *Context* menu appear > *LoopTools* > *Loft*. The pipe appear. You can tweak some parameters in the *Operator* box (bottom left).

[image]

**LoopTools > Bridge**

This solution is not as precise as you don't determine any intermediate. Select the first and last circles, then right click to make the *Context* menu appear > *LoopTools* > *Bridge*. The pipe appear. You can tweak some parameters in the *Operator* box (bottom left).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I would convert the edges from the path to a curve and then
use one of the edges from the MotorObjects as Bevelobject.

so you have to select the Edges that make the path first and hit "P" to 
seperate them.

Same goes for one of the rings that is your end or start ring select 
only the ring and hit "P" -
seperate by selection.

then go back to object level and select the path. 
go to object menu and search convert to curve.
after convert, go into edit mode and hit curve set Spline type 
to make it a bezier curve

Same for the other object you have seperated.
now you can use the ring as Bevel Object in
 Properties Panel - Curve - Bevel

set curve resolution to 1

go into edit mode for the "ring" and move it to the center
of the Scene and rotate it so it's on the ground like in the Picture: 
[image]

last but not least, move your path so it fits in the hole and use scale, rotate
and tilt on the first and last Control Point of your curve to match the object.

finally - convert your curve to mesh and join and connect to your base mesh.

Cheerz

if somebody wants to make screenshots to illustrate the process - go for it.